# How to manually select aperture and shutter speed but have auto ISO on a Canon 7D?

Tags: aperture, shutter-speed, canon-7d, camera-controls, auto-iso

I want to be able to manually adjust aperture and shutter speed, but leave ISO being set automatically. How can I do this on my Canon 7D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoping I haven't misunderstood your question, it is as simple as this:

- Turn Dial on top left of Camera to “M”
- Press the “Q” button on the back of the camera
- Set ISO to auto

Alternatively

- Turn Dial on top left of Camera to "M"
- Press the ISO Button on top of Camera and turn the top dial to the left until you reach "A"

now you are free to set the aperture and shutter speed as you please, using the top dial for shutter speed and rear dial for aperture (unless you've changed things with custom functions).

Comment: I thought so too, But I hoped there would have been a dial setting for that as it allows me control of DOF

Comment: You hoped there would be a dial setting for what? You already have shutter speed and aperture, and you specifically asked for auto ISO. At a high level, there's nothing left to choose.

Comment: As far as I know, having a direct dial setting for this is unique to Pentax,  where it is called `TAv` mode. I find it very convenient to gave it separate from full `M` in this way,  so you can get either behavior without diving into menus.

Comment: On a Canon, you can select auto ISO / ISO 100 / 200 / etc by simply holding down the ISO button and twiddling a dial - no need for menus.

Comment: The 7D has a button for selecting ISO, so there's no need to deal with menus just to set ISO to automatic. You don't even need to hold the button -- just press it once and select the setting you want.

Comment: @CorruptedMyStack Alternatively, if you want a dial setting, just configure one of your `C1`, `C2`, or `C3` configs to a manual auto-iso setup.  There is no expressing how handy it is to have go-to settings assigned to custom configs on the dial.

Comment: You will probably find useful to limit the maximum usable ISO value in the menu (third page -> "ISO auto") for the automatic ISO selection.

Comment: I had a pentax before that had that TAv mode so I was talking about that. Now I fully understand various methods to achieve that. Thanks